# How to switch a website theme to darkmode on load using a js snippet (from within the browser snippets)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, binance

I got limited web development skills and wonder if someone can point me into the right direction on how to change a preset them (light) to (dark) for binance.com.

I can see that the default theme is not set in the cookie but "theme = dark" gets added when toggle the switch (upper right). While I am able to modify a css selector in CSS, this goes beyond my skills. Any idea please?

Context: Eve if added to settings, it seems it doesn get respected all the time and while trading at night having those shiny white pages flashing up when I change the URL (e.g. checking balance, other pairs, ...) destroys me.

Any help is appreciated (even though knowing noone like these kind of requests)